# EF6 - Assign Entities to variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with 3 database in EF. These database have the same tables, just different data. When I get a value, I need to query a specific database.
Example:

- If I get value 1, I have to make the query to the database 1.
- .. value 2, to the database 2.
- .. value 3, to the database 3.

Every database got a different entity/dbContext obviously:

- Database1Entities
- Database2Entities
- Database3Entities

I wonder if there is a way to assign the entity to a variable, and then pass this variable to a method like this:

```
    public IQueryable<table> GetRecordsByNumBolla(string numBolla, **ENTITY**)
    {
        var dbContext = new **ENTITY**();
        var record = dbContext.Set<table1>().Where(x => x.number == numBolla);
        return record;
    }
```

I know there are some work around to this problem, however, if that's possible it will optimize the code and I will write less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that 3 databases have same tables (i.e. schema). That means those databases can be represented by same `Entity/DbContext` but different instances. Make a note here you need 3 different instances of the same `Entity/DbContext` in order to access data in respective databases.

You can use an approach to get respective `ConnectionString` and create `DbContext` dynamically. Once you get instance of `DbContext` you pass it as parameter to funtion `GetRecordsByNumBolla` in order to get data.

Code snippet could be as:

```
// The class that represents database schema based on which databases 
// are created. 
public partial class DatabaseEntity : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseEntity(string dbConn)
        : base(dbConn)
    {

    }
}

// This function creates instance of DbContext using connection string 
// for that database represented by parameter dbNumber. 
public DbContext GetDBContext(int dbNumber)
{
  //Get connection string which may be different for different database 
  string dbConnection = GetConnectionString(dbNumber);

  //Create appropriate instance
  var dbContext= new DatabaseEntity(dbConnection);

  return dbContext;
}

// Function to get data
public IQueryable<table> GetRecordsByNumBolla(string numBolla, DbContext dbContext)
{
  var record = dbContext.Set<table1>().Where(x => x.number == numBolla);
  return record;
}

private string GetConnectionString(int dbNumber)
{
    string connString = "";
    switch (dbNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            connString = @"server=localhost;database=DB1;uid=uid1;password=pwd1";
            break;
        case 2:
            connString = @"server=localhost;database=DB2;uid=uid2;password=pwd2";
            break;
        case 3:
            connString = @"server=localhost;database=DB3;uid=uid3;password=pwd3";
            break;
    }
    return connString;
}

//Code snippet to use these functions
var dbContext = GetDBContext(1); //For 1st database

var record = GetRecordsByNumBolla("XYZ",dbContext);
```